# Некорректная кодировка при выводе результатов JS/NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка

Здравствуйте,

Столкнулся со странной проблемой, код ниже лезет на страницы из списка, проходится по структуре, и забирает все **TR** в **TBODY** таблицы. Результаты объединяются и выводятся в консоль.

**Проблема:** Все строки с кириллическими символами заменяются на �������� �����������,�����������

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

pages = {
    p1 : 'page1.html',
    p2 : 'page2.html',
    p3 : 'page3.html'
}

for (page in pages) {
    var url = 'http://localhost:80/' + pages[page];
    request(url, ( function(page) {
        return function(err, resp, body) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            $ = cheerio.load(body);

            $('table tbody').each(function() {
                $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
                    console.log(/*page + ',' + */$(this).text() + ';');
                });
            });
        }
    } )(page));
}
```

Я попробовал другой способ, с ним никаких проблем, кроме того, что скрипт придется выполнять на каждой странице вручную :)

```
var xTable = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
var xRows = xTable[0].rows;
var xCells = xTable[0].getElementsByTagName('td');

for (i = 0; i < xRows.length; i++) {
    iCell = xRows.item(i).cells;
    console.log(iCell[0], iCell[1]);
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я упускаю и в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Судя по всему влияет кодировка win1251 в <head> целевого сайта. Но на каком этапе ее менять, при загрузке страницы Cheerio или при выводе в консоль...

Comment: Решение оказалось тривиальным: использовать еще один модуль.

    var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
    ...
    console.log(iconv.decode (new Buffer (page + '$' + $(this).text().trim().replace(/\s\s\s\s+/g, '$') +'$', 'binary'), 'win1251'));